# What does it mean to review a declined flag?

Tags: support, flagging

Recently one my flags was declined (OP revised the flagged post after I flagged it).  However now when I go to flag a post the flag window says

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

and the flag button is grayed out.  "Review it" links to my page of past flags.  But I see now option to review or do anything with any of the flags.  What does it mean to review a declined flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the page linked in the message: [Your flags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/5705) (only viewable to you and mods). This is the same page that the "Helpful Flags" link on the "Activity" tab of your profile page goes to.

There is no button, or anything like in the review queue. All SE wants you to do is read the message under the flag(s) in question, and make sure you understand why your flag was declined.

---

You still can flag posts (it says so on your flags page).

> **Flagging status**
>
> - Not banned from flagging
> - Warned when flagging

You can read the details about how the flag warning and banning system works here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/278094.

In short:
If you flag more then 10 flags per week you will get warned when more then 10% are declined, and temporarily banned if more then 25% are declined.

If you have less then 10 per week (this is your case at the moment) you will get warned if your last flag was declined.

Comment: Hmmm... I did go there, both before I tried to flag another one and several times by clicking the given link, and it still won't let me do any more flagging.

Comment: @PGmath see updated answer (from what I've read I think the grayed out button will still work)